# MYSQL репликация и работа триггеров

Tags: mysql

Добрый день.
Имеется настроенная репликация Master-Slave
На Slave необходимо добавить триггеры что бы не нагружать основную базу.
Проблема в том что часть триггеров срабатывает а часть нет.
Тип репликации binlog-format=mixed.
Читал что для того что бы триггеры на slave отрабатывали параметр binlog-format на master должен быть STATEMENT.

p.s. на локальной версии все тригеры работают.

Версия MySQl 5.6.34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Документация не столь категорична.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-features-triggers.html

> to enable slave-side triggers, it is not necessary to use statement-based replication exclusively. It is sufficient to **switch to statement-based replication only for those statements where you want this effect**, and to use row-based replication the rest of the time.

Плюс ремарка там же, которую не стОит пропускать:

> A statement invoking a trigger (or function) that causes an update to an AUTO_INCREMENT column is not replicated correctly using statement-based replication. MySQL 5.6 **marks such statements as unsafe**.

Советую посмотреть ту же статью, но для 5,7. Там чуть поболе текста.

Comment: Тоесть получается что для того чтобы тригеры заработали на slave необходимо для таблиц на которые используются тригеррами использовать statement-based replication, но в этом случае на этих таблицах возникнут проблемы с полями auto_increment. Правильно я понял ? Тоесть получается что для того чтобы заработали тригеры я должен отказаться от auto_increment?

Comment: Ну почти так. С той лишь оговоркой, что речь идёт о случаях, когда происходит _**обновление**_ поля-автоинкремента. А поскольку это делается крайне нечасто, то, наверное, ограничение можно локализовать как относящееся к BEFORE UPDATE триггерам - точно, и AFTER UPDATE - возможно (и точно, если он изменяет сгенерированное автоинкрементом значение).

Comment: Ну в принципе нормальный вариант решения проблемы. Я если честно не могу представить ситуацию когда необходимо менять поле автоинкремента.

Comment: И еще маленький вопрос. Как добиться вот этого "switch to statement-based replication only for those statements where you want this effect" тоесть как я понял необходимо както настроить репликацию чтобы на определенные таблицы использовалась только Statement. И возможно ли это сделать на горячую, без перезапуска мастера?

Comment: А вот тут ничего не скажу. Нет у меня опыта работы с репликацией в боевых условиях, а модельки - это не то... впрочем, и у вас тоже "на локальной версии работает".

Answer (score 0):

Для корректной работы триггеров на slave репликация должна быть настроена как statement.

> If you want triggers to execute on both the master and the slave—perhaps because you have different triggers on the master and slave—you must use statement-based replication.

[Ссылка на документацию](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-features-triggers.html).